# Typescript Union of function with other type throws error

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to have a property with a union type of a function and a string.

```
export type IMenuItem = {
    target: string | (val1:any[], val2:number) => number;
}
```

TS playground sample can be accessed [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCSBZYA7ArmmYAWzgF44BvAWACg56EBDKAc2BgC44BnGKAS2ws4AHzgAKAG6MANgEYOjbIgDaAXQA0caTIBMHPEQBGwKAEoyAPjiGTUANy0AvkA).

**But the TS compiler gives an error: "Function type notation must be parenthesized when used in a union type."**

Is the type declared incorrectly? Or is there a workaround for this?

However, it works if we remove the union.

```
export type IMenuItem = {
    target: (val1:any[], val2:number) => number;
}
```

Comment: you are missing the parenthesis: `target: string | ((val1:any[], val2:number) => number)`

Comment: That error message specifically tells you what to do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap you function with parenthesizes

```
export type IMenuItem = {
    target: string | ((val1:any[], val2:number) => number);
}
```